# Joining 2 tables with limited joining conditions

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, join, teradata

I am quite new to SQL and I am trying to join two tables,

**Table A:**

```
ID  Amount    Bank 
123  50        Barclays
123  50        tesco
123  50        HSBC
123  100       LLyods
123  200       MBNA
```

**Table B:**

```
ID  Amount    Bank
123  50        aa
123  50        bb
123  50        cc
123  100       dd
123  200       ee
```

Note that: in table B the bank name is the same as table A but it is written in a different format, so I can't join on this.

the script i am running is:

```
Select A.*, B.*
FROM TableA  A
Left Join TableB B
on A.ID = B.ID AND A.AMOUNT = B.AMOUNT
;
```

The result i get is,

```
ID  Amount  Bank    ID  AMOUNT  BANK
123 50  Barclays    123 50      aa
123 50  Barclays    123 50      bb
123 50  Barclays    123 50      cc
123 50  tesco       123 50      aa
123 50  tesco       123 50      bb
123 50  tesco       123 50      cc
123 50  HSBC        123 50      aa
123 50  HSBC        123 50      bb
123 50  HSBC        123 50      cc
123 100 LLyods      123 100     dd
123 200 MBNA        123 200     ee
```

what i want to get is,

```
ID  Amount  Bank    ID  AMOUNT  BANK
123 50  Barclays    123 50      aa
123 50  tesco       123 50      bb
123 50  HSBC        123 50      cc
123 100 LLyods      123 100     dd
123 200 MBNA        123 200     ee
```

I get the issue is that it joining each row of table A to the rows of table B which meet the join conditions; unfortunately the table B has no other unique values that I can use as a join condition;

Can the community please see if you can think of something, I would very much appreciate it. Thank you :)

Comment: teradata or SQL Server?

Comment: You are creating a many to many relationship with that join. Is there a way to relate the bank column in table A to the bank column in table B. Maybe create a column in table A that has those symbols in table B?

Comment: teradata; @hollow_Victory this is a small sample example; the bank column has 200 distinct values and i can't join them using that

Comment: @Samar well I think at this point all you can create is a messy cross-join from the N to N relationship between the two tables.

Comment: yeah that's what i was thinking, i was hoping someone faced something like before and came up with a creative way to get around this :)

Comment: @Samar: Maybe if you can change the representation of the bank column by adding a column and using id, amount and bank every row could match up but that's not certain.

Comment: @Samar can you alter the table that way?

Comment: can you elaborate a bit please

Comment: Well there should be a way to relate the two bank columns between the two tables. How do the letters in table B for the bank column relate to the names in bank column for table A?

Comment: You have to have some criteria for deciding that the bank Barclay's in table A is equivalent to the bank aa in table B. That is missing from your question.

Comment: But basically if there is no primary key in at least one table for a many to one relation then the join will just be a cross-join.

Comment: Can you show some actual examples of the different band names?

Comment: @SamarVijay: How are you so sure that `Barclays` corresponds to `aa`;  `tesco` to `bb` and so on.......

Answer (score 1):

you can use inner join for your desired result

```
Select A.*
B.*
FROM TableA  A
 INNER JOIN TableB B
   on A.ID = B.ID
    AND A.AMOUNT = B.AMOUNT
;
```

Comment: That still creates a cross-join from the many to many relation.

Comment: inner join gives me the same result

Comment: @– Samar Vijay: Inner join gives you what he wants?

Comment: @hollow_Victory no it gives me the same result as my problem

Comment: @Samar: Im sorry I got mixed up.

Comment: @hollow_Victory no worries, i should've clarified

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to create a third table, matching the Table A Bank values to their corresponding Table B Bank values? Because without some sort of linking table specifying the relationship, the SQL server has no way of knowing that 'Barclays' = 'aa', 'tesco' = 'bb', etc. There has to be some sort of unique relationship, and you don't have that in the two tables provided.

**LinkTable:**

```
Code    Bank 
aa       Barclays
bb   tesco
cc   HSBC
dd   LLyods
e    MBNA
```

You can then do:

```
Select A.*, B.*
FROM TableA  A
  JOIN LinkTable LB ON (A.Bank = LB.Bank)
  JOIN TableB B ON (LB.ID = B.Bank);
```

Comment: Be careful here though. Think about the join. So joining Table A to LinkTable will create a many to one but after that joining Table B will create a many to many. The joins would be sequential.

Answer (score 0):

To directly get the output you want, you can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON on A.ID = B.ID AND A.AMOUNT = B.AMOUNT
AND 
(
    (a.Bank = 'Barclays' AND b.bank = 'aa') OR
    (a.Bank = 'tesco' AND b.bank = 'bb') OR
    (a.Bank = 'HSBC' AND b.bank = 'cc') OR
    (a.Bank = 'Lloyds' AND b.bank = 'dd') OR
    (a.Bank = 'MBNA' AND b.bank = 'ee')
)
```

But this is ugly and not a great solution if you have hundreds of mappings.  It also assumes that (Bank, ID, Amount) is your PK for both tables.  The best way is to have a link/mapping table, like MorbidGnome suggested above and include that in your joins.

If you're not pulling any data from TableB (like in your example), then you can just use a CASE statement instead of joining to TableB:

```
SELECT a.*,
  CASE a.Bank 
    WHEN 'Barclays' THEN 'aa'
    WHEN 'tesco' THEN 'bb'
    WHEN 'HSBC' THEN 'cc'
    WHEN 'Lloyds' THEN 'dd'
    WHEN 'MBNA' THEN 'ee'
  END AS Bank_B
FROM TableA
```